# JQuery UI Button Moves Around on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a table with two large cells, the left cell containing two drop-downs and the JQuery UI button that I'm having trouble with, and the right cell contains a list that's generated from an AJAX database query. As the list grows, the button moves further and further upwards, to the point where it begins to block one of the drop-downs. When I mouse-over the button, it moves down the page a few centimeters. No matter how big the list is, this button always moves down upon mouse-over, and I can't figure out why or how to prevent this from happening.

JQuery:

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

 <link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#createReport").button({
      icons: {
         primary: "ui-icon-document"
      }
   });
});

</head>
```

Table:

```
<table style="width:600px;table-layout:fixed;"><tr>
    <td style="height:10px;background-color:#3882C7;color:#FFD23A;"><b>Create New Reports</b></td>
    <td style="height:10px;background-color:#3882C7;color:#FFD23A;"><b>Reports Completed for this Month - <span id="section"></span></b></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding:20px;">
            <p>Court:&nbsp;<select id="newReportsDD">
            <option>Criminal</option>
            <option>Civil</option>
            <option>Family</option>
            <option>Business</option>
            </select></p>
            <p><?php echo judgesDropDown('newReportsJudgeDD'); ?></p><br/>
            <p><button id = "createReport">Create/Edit Report</button></p>
        </div></td>
    <td style="padding:10px;"><div id ="judgesCompleted"><!-- AJAX GENERATED LIST --></div>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Couple of points: I see an extra `</div>` immediately after the createReport button.  Also, does the button, when you mouse over it, move to its intended position, and when you mouse off, does it stay where it was or move again?

Comment: Thanks, took that extra </div> out. Upon mouse-over, the button moves to its intended place, it starts out in a weird position.

Comment: Are you applying any CSS not shown in your code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <td id="container" style="padding:20px;">
        <p>Court:&nbsp;<select id="newReportsDD">
        <option>Criminal</option>
        <option>Civil</option>
        <option>Family</option>
        <option>Business</option>
        </select></p>
        <p><?php echo judgesDropDown('newReportsJudgeDD'); ?></p><br/>
        <p><button id = "createReport">Create/Edit Report</button></p>
    </div></td>
```

#container {vertical-align: top;
        text-align: left;}